# Variable Assignment and passing to other function

Tags: c++

I got a command line utility code written in C++.
This code is having its own main() function.
Now I want to write my program on the top of this.So I am declaring my own main() and making the utility's main() function as some another function lets say Test().

now the Test() is as:

```
int Test(_In_ int argc, _In_reads_(argc) PWSTR* argv){
.
.
.
}//doing some work
```

I want to pass arguements to the Test() from main()

My Implementation of main() is as:

```
int main(){
int argc=3;
PWSTR* argval=NULL;
    PWSTR ptr1 = _TEXT("asd");
    PWSTR ptr2 = _TEXT("fzx");
    PWSTR ptr3 = _TEXT("qwe"); 
        argval[0]=ptr1;
    argval[1]=ptr2;
    argval[2]=ptr3;
        Test(argc,argval);
}
```

when I am building this project it is giving the following run time..
Unhandled exception at 0x00E4999F in devcon.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

I have doubt whether I am assigning it correctly..? But I might be wrong.

I am building this project in visual studio 2012 on windows 7 machine..

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer argval is not pointing to anything. You need to allocate memory for that.
Try

```
PWSTR* argval = new PWSTR[3];
```

Comment: Actually what you mention is C style memory allocation. If you are using C++, then the one I suggested is the preferred method of dynamically allocating memory. It is in general not a good idea to mix C with C++ unless absolutely necessary.